# Копирование части строки из memo в Edit

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe5

**Есть:**

```
Edit1.Text
Edit2.Text 
Edit3.Text
Edit4.Text
```

**В Memo1 первая строка:**

```
User1/15/21.06.12/568
```

**Я нажимаю кнопку и переносим значения с Memo.Lines[0]. То есть с первой строки Memo в Edit:**

```
Edit1.Text = User1
Edit2.Text = 15
Edit3.Text = 21.06.12
Edit4.Text = 568
```

Формат строки постоянно один и разделитель между значениями знак **/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sl := TStringList.Create;
sl.Delimiter := '/';
sl.DelimitedText := Memo1.Lines[0];
```

И берёте кусочки из sl[i]

Comment: Благодарен, работает.